# How do I quickly increase city civilization rating?

Tags: civcity-rome

I'm playing CivCity-Rome in Campaign mode (2nd mission).

I already added a lot of fountains and gardens, increased the clean service and work time + wages + rations are all happy faces (+3 each). Also already discovered everything that exist to discover.

The city needs 70 points of city civilization rating, but the max I managed to have is 50.

Is there a way to improve it permanently?

I already check [this guide](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/help-for-your-civcities-inside.124231710/) but there is nothing I didn't use yet.

Comment: I could check that from home, but first state if you in sandbox or in campaign mode, and if so which mission then?

Comment: @Sanctus updated the question with some extra info. Thanks for your help! I'm welcoming any strategy to increase city civilization rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked myself, and if we are talking about the same mission, there is no needs for 70 Civ points. However, it is hard to navigate in mission structure of CivCity:Rome because they reuse the same cities in next missions, so next time please state at least city name and mission goals.

For more Civ points you first have to check what do you have already on the Report screen. The top-most report is about Civ rating (column icon). It is composed from the four categories of:

1. Entertainment (red)
2. Religion (green)
3. Civic Services (blue)
4. Splendor (yellow)

So if you want more, first check what's missing from here. You might not be able to construct all necessary buildings (yet) in some missions so it is okay to not have maximum rating all the time.

Another typical mistake (though not in your case) is to misread Empire points and Civilization points. For more Empire points you goal might be to deliver more fresh goods to Senate.

Refer to this walkthrough in case of more questions https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/932339-civcity-rome/faqs/48086

Comment: thanks for the link, but it was actually talking about the city civilization rating... One thing that I made to rapidly increase city civilization rating was planting an outrageous amount of gardens and such... a few missions later, I also added more religion access, more culture access and all those things together make the city civilization rating increase.

Comment: @vianna77, nice, glad you solved your issue. But keep in mind two things. First, it is hard to navigate in mission structure in CivCity because they reuse the same cities with for next mission, so next time please state something more precise (city name, and mission goals). Second, early missions are introductory so if you dont have any issues with mission goals but trying to "Continue" after end, it may be not possible to reach certain results.

Comment: What you said is so true that I thought that I had finished the game but I actually finished one part of it! It is quite confusing... and my post reflect that confusion!

Comment: I had the same feelings, when was finishing this game (ages ago) last time.